# Is it possible to addClass to each element containing a regex match in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, string, each

Is there a way to write a jQuery function using regex so that for each span, if its content begins with a number, it gets an added class of "numberFirst" ?

```
<span>123 abc</span> <!-- should get new class -->
<span>abc 123</span> <!-- should not -->
<span>456 def</span> <!-- should -->
```

Can it be done with `.addClass()` or do you have to replace all the html with

`<span class='numberFirst'>$1</span>`

Comment: Yes, there most certainly is a way. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/^[^\D]/);
}).addClass('numberFirst');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GjuZD/)

Comment: @nathanbweb - not sure why you'd want a regex, but sure!

Comment: great, thanks. this was a reduced test case; other matches I'm trying to make aren't just based on numbers.

Comment: Well, there you go, short and pretty easy to understand.

Comment: @nathanbweb we can't tell you how to do it if you don't tell us what you want. Learn from the example given.